# using formcollection to show data on view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two action methods in my controller class both with same name. One of them is `httpGet` and the other one is `HttpPost`. I have created one view to input values. Now I need to sum these values and show it to other view.

My problem is, I can't create two views with same name in same views folder.

The second Action method is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(FormCollection formCollection)
{           
    return View(formCollection);
}
```

where `formCollection` holds values entered by user. I need to sum these values and show them to the other view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quite get what you need but maybe you could return a specific view:

`return View("Result", formCollection);`

HTH